# events don't invoke in cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, nswindow

Here's a header file:

```
@interface MainDreamer : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate>
{    
    IBOutlet NSTextField *myField;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *myTable;    
    IBOutlet NSImageView *myView;

    IBOutlet NSMutableArray *mylist;  
    IBOutlet NSMutableArray *dataset;
}

- (IBAction)addRecord:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)deleterecord:(id)sender;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

I implemented several events in .m file:

```
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSLog(@"mouse down");
}

- (void) mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSLog(@"mouse up");
}

- (void) tableViewSelectionDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification{
    NSLog(@"selected row changed");
}

- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}
```

However neither of them are invoked (I checked it by putting in a breakpoint).

Other methods in the program work fine including, so everything with wires seems to be OK.

Why don't the events handlers launch?

Comment: What happens when you click on the background of the window?

Comment: Nothing happens wherever I click and log is empty. Events handlers just don't launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your xib file and click on your window, what is the "Custom Class" type set to?  `NSWindow` or `MainDreamer`.

The fact it's not hitting any of your methods tells me it's still set to `NSWindow`.  Try setting your "Custom Class" to `MainDreamer` and see what happens then.